# Disable default keybaord open on EditText click

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I want that when i click on my EditText (messageText), if the keyboard is open i close it, else i close it.

```
messageText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @OverridesetOnClickListener 
            public void onClick(View v){
                 if(imm.isActive()){
                     imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                 }
            }
        });
```

It doesn't work because by default it open the keyboard when i click on my EditText so the imm.isActive() is always true.
How can I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it easily from Manifeast.xml

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" 
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```